# Port Forwarded, still cannot see IISExpress webserver

Tags: windows-8, port-forwarding, iis-7.5

I am using IISExpress. I have a BSNL modem(Name: VMC 21, ModelNo: AN1020-21). I've set up port forwarding to port 5069. My static IP address is 192.168.1.121 - I am using DynDNS.

My problem is, I am unable to see my website hosted in IISExpress from the outside.

I can also see my router's admin page on port 80

PS: I am using Windows 8.